# Fancybox just display one group at home

Tags: jquery, fancybox

On fancybox I want the homepage to display just one group of images example "quadri" I don't want display ".seri" images if I click on "serigrafie" I want to see images of "seri" how can I can do it? this is my code:

```html
<div class="filter-categories filter-mixitup">
        <span class="btn filter " data-filter="quadri">Quadri su legno e varie</span>
        <span class="btn filter " data-filter=".seri">Serigrafie </span>
        <span class="btn filter " data-filter=".mini">Miniature (Prossimamente)</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Filter Categories - End -->
    <!-- Portfolio Items - Start -->
    <div class="filter-items quadri filter-mixitup  inviewport animated " data-effect="fadeIn" id="gallery-mixitup">
        <!-- Item - Start -->
        <div class="filter-item quadri col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6  col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <img alt="gallery-image" src="img/gallery-1.jpg" class="img-responsive transition">
            <div class="info transition">
                <a class="btn btn-primary fancybox" title="Quadro n° 1 cm: 80 x 78" data-filter="quadri" href="img/gallery-1.jpg"><i class="mdi mdi-image-area"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item - End -->
        <!-- Item - Start -->
        <div class="filter-item quadri col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6  col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <img alt="gallery-image" src="img/gallery-2.jpg" class="img-responsive transition">
            <div class="info transition">
                <a class="btn btn-primary fancybox" title="Quadro n° 2 cm: 94 x 35"  data-fancybox-group="quadri" href="img/gallery-2.jpg"><i class="mdi mdi-image-area"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item - End -->
        <!-- Item - Start -->
        <div class="filter-item quadri col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6  col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <img alt="gallery-image" src="img/gallery-3.jpg" class="img-responsive transition">
            <div class="info transition">
                <a class="btn btn-primary fancybox" title="Quadro n° 3 cm: 123 x 103" data-fancybox-group="quadri" href="img/gallery-3.jpg"><i class="mdi mdi-image-area"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item - End -->`
<!-- Item - Start -->
        <div class="filter-item seri col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6  col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <img alt="gallery-image" src="img/seri/seri-1.jpg" class="img-responsive transition">
            <div class="info transition">
                <a class="btn btn-primary fancybox" title="Serigrafie n° 1 cm: 45x30" data-fancybox-group=".seri" href="img/seri/seri-1f.jpg"><i class="mdi mdi-image-area"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item - End -->
  <!-- Item - Start -->
        <div class="filter-item seri col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6  col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <img alt="gallery-image" src="img/seri/seri-2.jpg" class="img-responsive transition">
            <div class="info transition">
                <a class="btn btn-primary fancybox" title="Serigrafie n° 2 cm: 45x30" data-fancybox-group=".seri" href="img/seri/seri-2f.jpg"><i class="mdi mdi-image-area"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item - End -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Isotope for filtering and then use fancyBox manually to open visible items:

```
// Custom click event - open fancyBox manually
$('.fancybox').on('click', function() {
  var visibleLinks = $('.fancybox:visible');

  $.fancybox.open( visibleLinks, {}, visibleLinks.index( this ) );

  return false;
});
```

Working demo - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/EZKYPN?editors=1010